# Google Analytics - get unique users by country

Tags: google-analytics, geolocation

I want to know, how my users are splitted by countries. In Google Analytics there is Audience/Geo section where I can see how many **sessions** I have from each country. But I want to know how many **users** I have in each country. I did not found how to view 'users' metrics in the GEO report.

So, is there a way to get the **users** splitted by countries in GA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do with the the "Users" metric (`ga:users`) and the "Country" dimension (`ga:country`). Here's [an example report showing this using the Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=3daysAgo&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3Acountry&sort=-ga%3Ausers&max-results=10).

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Audience > Geo > Location report and add the Users metric to the results.  After clicking the customize option on that report (in the upper left of the screen under the title "Location"), you can add the Users metric to your metric group (The Users metric is categorized under the the "Users" category).  Here's an example of doing this using the UI:

[image]

After saving the edits to the report, it can be found again under the Customization area of the Google Analytics UI